# Calling http.get multiple times in a RxJS pipeline

Tags: angular, rxjs, http-get

I need to process a `http.get` response multiple times in a unique RxJS pipeline. Here is a part of the JSON response:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "layerName": "Primary",
    "hierarchyCount": 2,
    "layerHierarchies": [
      {
        "hierarchyOrder": 1,
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Secant Piles"
      },
      {
        "hierarchyOrder": 2,
        "id": 6,
        "name": "As-Designed"
      }
    ],
    "gisViewTypeId": "M1",
    "coordinateSystemId": 5,
    "verticalCoordinateSystemId": 7,
    "measurementUnitSymbol": null,
    "color": "#fabed4",
    "stroke": true,
    "weight": 3,
    "opacity": 1,
    "fill": true,
    "fillColor": "#f032e6",
    "fillOpacity": 0.2,
    "active": false,
    "pointTypeId": 2,
    "shiftX": 0,
    "shiftY": 0
  },
...
]
```

Through the following pipeline I get the max of `hierarchyCount` as follows:

```js
    this.layerHierarchi$ = this.http.get<LayerHierarchiesEntity[]>(baseURL + "Structure/StructureHierarchy", { params: layerParams, headers: headers })
    return this.layerHierarchi$.pipe(
      mergeMap((value) => from(value)),
      pluck("hierarchyCount"),
      max(),
      // mergeMap(maxHierarchyCount => this.layerHierarchi$),
    )
```

As you can see, in the very last line of the pipeline which is commented, I try to get the original `http.get` response to continue processing.
I am not sure making another call in the `mergeMap` operator is correct or there is another technique or RxJS operator to take care of that? In other words, I need the original response multiple times throughout the pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem right, I would consider a solution along these lines. Comments inline

```
this.layerHierarchi$ = this.http.get<LayerHierarchiesEntity[]>(baseURL + "Structure/StructureHierarchy", { params: layerParams, headers: headers })
return this.layerHierarchi$.pipe(
  // process the result of the http call and extract within the function passed to mergeMap
  // you should use the map operator
  map((value) => {
      // the following map is the array method, NOT the map rxjs operator
     hierCounts = value.map(v => v.hierarchyCount);
     hierMax = Math.max(...hierCounts)  // assume hierarchyCount is a number
     return [value, hierMax]
  }),
  mergeMap(([value, hierMax]) => // do what you need to do to continue processing),
)
```

Some additional considerations.

You have been using the `mergeMap` operator passing to it a function which returns an Observable created by the `from` rxjs function to which you passed an Array.

Unless you have very good reasons to do so, I would prefer to process arrays using javascript array functions as in my example.

If within your further processing you need to execute other cascaded http calls, then consider to use `concatMap` rather than `mergeMap`. You may find some inspiration about typical patterns of use of rxjs with http [in this article](https://medium.com/me/stats/post/ef636c9af19a).

Comment: I understand your solution but that is not the Angular way of resolving the issue. As you can see, the original JSON file is an array of objects. you have to split the array using ```for``` or ```of``` operators to use ```max``` operator.

Comment: I am proposing to use the `max` function of `Math` NOT the `max` rxjs operator